# What is a good way to integrate formik with material-table?

Tags: reactjs, formik, material-table

I'm trying to add formik to my table I built with [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/material-table.js).  Is there a way to another way to access the api to integrate it with formik?

Here's the table I'm using:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MaterialTable, { FormField, MTableEditRow } from "material-table";
import { Formik, Field, getIn } from "formik";

const FormikField = props => (
  <Field
    name={props.columnDef.field}
    render={({ field, form }) => {
      const { name } = field;
      const { errors, setFieldValue } = form;

      const showError = !!getIn(errors, name);

      return (
        <FormField
          {...props}
          {...field}
          error={showError}
          onChange={newValue => setFieldValue(name, newValue)}
        />
      );
    }}
  />
);

const MuiTableEditRow = ({ onEditingApproved, ...props }) => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={props.data}
    onSubmit={newData => {
      delete newData.tableData;
      onEditingApproved(props.mode, newData, props.data);
    }}
    render={({ submitForm }) => (
      <MTableEditRow {...props} onEditingApproved={submitForm} />
    )}
  />
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MaterialTable
        data={[{ id: 1, firstName: "ax", firstName: "Baran" }]}
        columns={[
          { title: "First Name", field: "firstName" },
          { title: "Last Name", field: "lastName" }
        ]}
        editable={{
          onRowAdd: newData =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              resolve();
            })
        }}
        components={{
          EditRow: MuiTableEditRow,
          FormField: FormikField
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the EditField component can access the table with formik:

Here are the edits to the above code:

```
// imports

...
const FormikMTInput = props => (
   <Field
     name={props.columnDef.field}
     render={({field, form}) => {
       const {name} = field
       const {errors, setFieldValue} = form

       const showError = !!getIn(errors, name)

       return (
         <div>
           <MTableEditField
             {...props}
             {...field}
             error={showError}
             onChange={newValue => setFieldValue(name, newValue)}
           />
           {errors[field.name] && (
             <div style={{color: "#f44336"}}>{errors[field.name]}</div>
           )}
         </div>
       )
     }}
   />
 )

...

const MuiTableEditRow = ({onEditingApproved, ...props}) => (
   <Formik
     validationSchema={courseLevelSchema} // included a validation object
     initialValues={props.data}
     onSubmit={values => {
       delete values.tableData
       onEditingApproved(props.mode, values, props.data)
     }}
     render={({submitForm}) => (
       <MTableEditRow {...props} onEditingApproved={submitForm} />
     )}
   />
 )

... 

<Material

...

 components={{
      EditRow: MuiTableEditRow,
      EditField: FormikMTInput
 }}

...

/>
```

Comment: Hi! This works but not with some problems from my experience. I'm having trouble with the line delete values.tableData. If you have it, it gives problems when deleting or when editing and confirm edit with no changes.
If you remove it, the previous cases work but editing a row and making a change makes the table to not leave edit mode even after confirming it. If it wasn't for that problem, the solution is really good!
Any thoughts? 
Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked with material-table since last year due to another project so I really don't know.  You could bring this up in the Gitter material-table lobby.  It remains current with good community support.